# Image Resizing Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

I am using the `image_lib` class in CodeIgniter to re-size images, it works fine; here is my code:

```
function resizeImage($source_image,$new_image,$width=100,$height=100){
       $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
       $config['source_image']  = $source_image;
       $config['new_image'] = $new_image;
       $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
       $config['width']  = $width;
       $config['height']    = $height;
       $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

       if($this->image_lib->resize()) return true;
       else return false;
}
```

However, what I am trying to achieve, no matter what image it is, landscape, or portrait. Big small. The images are cropped to set dimensions.

Currently, after they are cropped this way, the images come out as different sized thumbs, mainly if it is landscape or portrait. Whereas if you go into a web site such as [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/) you will see that all of the thumbs are exactly the same proportion, width and height.

How can I accomplish this?

Cheers.

EDIT

Excellent tutorial to do exactly this, can be found here:

[CodeIgniter.tv](http://codeigniter.tv/a-8/Create-multiple-aspect-ratio-thumbnails)

---

I am trying to crop and proportionally resize thumbs in CI, as shown here:

> OK, then you could crop the images to a square image first, then
>   resize. Take a look here: stackoverflow.com/a/3327424/844726 –
>   swatkins Jun 26 at 13:33

```
function resizeImg(){
   $source_image = base_url().'pic2.jpg';
   $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
   $config['source_image']  = $source_image;
   $config['new_image'] = $new_image;
   $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
   $config['x_axis'] = '10';
   $config['y_axis'] = '10';
   $config['width']  = $width;
   $config['height']    = $height;
   $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
}
```

When I run the script like this:

```
http://localhost/test/index.php/cronJobs/resizeImg
```

I get a server error, I guess the script didnt execute.

Comment: Well, one approach is to feed the system only images of the same proportion. You can automate this through doing some cropping before the resizing, but chances are the cropped area will never be the ideal one. That's why sites like Facebook offer a cropping dialog. [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) could help you with that, but it's significantly more work to implement than a simple resize.

Comment: Am I better off using this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/ to all the image resizing for me, rather then using the CI class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;` statement. This tells the system to keep the proportion of width to height as a ratio to the new width or height (based on which is the larger value).

So, if an image is portrait, it will resize to 100px high, but width will be proportionate to the original image ratio.

If you want the image to be 100px X 100px, then you need to set:

```
$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach, it will mean that the image will be distorted, as it will just resize them all to 100x100 without properly cropping them then resizing in ratio

Comment: OK, then you could crop the images to a square image first, then resize. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3327424/844726

Comment: Ok I am trying to test this like this - see my other answer to the question which is below:

Comment: You might take a look at this page: http://superdit.com/2010/07/14/cropping-image-to-square-dimension-with-codeigniter/

Comment: Checked it out, not getting an output, are you? Copied and pasted exactly, only lines I changed was: 
    $img_path = base_url().'pic2.jpg';
    $img_thumb = base_url().'pic2thumb.jpg';

Comment: got it to work, removed base_url. Quick question, can I designated so that it crops a specific part of the picture, as it seems to be cropping the top left hand corner where in some pics it would be better to crop the centre of it

Comment: Found this excellent tutorial for anyone that is interested:
http://codeigniter.tv/a-8/Create-multiple-aspect-ratio-thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

For big site like BBC, they have to manually crop/resize images themselves, I think. 
With CodeIgniter, we can set like this:

```
$config_resize['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config_resize['master_dim'] = 'height';
$config_resize['quality'] = "100%";
$config_resize['source_image'] = './' . $user_upload_path . $file_name;

$config_resize['height'] = 64;
$config_resize['width'] = 1;
```

to fix the thumb height and maintain aspect ratio, [this post](http://4rapiddev.com/php/codeigniter-upload-and-resize-image-maintain-ratio/) shows example and demo for resizing.