# Codeigniter Image Library Cropping an Image with 2 sets of coordinates to make square anywhere?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, gd

Spending time reading through the docs, and searching for examples. I understand cropping an image from top 0, and left 0 is pretty straight forward. However. I would like to pass 2 sets of coordinates, a starting point and an ending point. Four Points, a Square that is defined anywhere. However from the examples I am finding, and from what I gather the rendition is not going to let me do this. codeigniter so I am seeking confirmation on this thought, is it true that I can only provide end points from 0, and it crops a square based on said end points or can I actually specify an x start, an x end, and similar for y?

Or is there some other technique I can use within codeigniter that will allow me to pass for coordinates for starting and ending points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example of class of defined cropping image and call it a class via library or helper in a codeigniter:

For example call it:

```
LibraryCropImage::ResizedThumbnail($profile_thumbsize_x, $profile_thumbsize_x, $path, $filename, $path_to, $filename_to.'_sized', $quality, $fileextension);
LibraryCropImage::CroppedThumbnail($profile_thumbsize_x, $profile_thumbsize_x, $path, $filename, $path_to, $filename_to.'_cropped', $quality, $fileextension);

abstract class LibraryCropImage  {

    function ResizedThumbnail($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $path, $filename, $path_to, $filename_to, $quality, $ext)
    {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path.$filename);

    $new_width = $thumbnail_width;
    $new_height = $thumbnail_height;

    if ($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg")
    {
        $thumb = @imagecreatefromjpeg($path.$filename);
    }
    else if ($ext == "gif")
    {
        $thumb = @imagecreatefromgif($path.$filename);
    }
    else if ($ext == "png")
    {
        $thumb = @imagecreatefrompng($path.$filename);
    }
    $thumbp = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);



    imagecopyresampled($thumbp, $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    ob_start();
    if ($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg")
    {
        imagejpeg($thumbp, null, $quality);
    }
    else if ($ext == "gif")
    {
        imagegif($thumbp);
    }
    else if ($ext == "png")
    {
        imagepng($thumbp, null);
    }
    $i = ob_get_clean();
    $fp = fopen($path_to.$filename_to.'.'.$ext, 'w');
    fwrite ($fp, $i);
    fclose ($fp);
    imagedestroy($thumbp);
    }

    function CroppedThumbnail($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $path, $filename, $path_to, $filename_to, $quality, $ext)
    {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path.$filename);

    $new_width = $thumbnail_width;
    $new_height = $thumbnail_height;

    if ($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg")
    {
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($path.$filename);
    }
    else if ($ext == "gif")
    {
        $image = @imagecreatefromgif($path.$filename);
    }
    else if ($ext == "png")
    {
        $image = @imagecreatefrompng($path.$filename);
    }

    $filename = $path.$filename;

    $thumb_width = $thumbnail_width;
    $thumb_height = $thumbnail_height;

    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);

    $original_aspect = $width / $height;
    $thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

    if($original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect) {
       // If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
       $new_height = $thumb_height;
       $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
    } else {
       // If the thumbnail is wider than the image
       $new_width = $thumb_width;
       $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
    }

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);

    // Resize and crop 
    imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                       $image,
                       0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
                       0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
                       0, 0,
                       $new_width, $new_height,
                       $width, $height);


    ob_start();
    if ($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg")
    {
        imagejpeg($thumb, null, $quality);
    }
    else if ($ext == "gif")
    {
        imagegif($thumb);
    }
    else if ($ext == "png")
    {
        imagepng($thumb, null);
    }
    $i = ob_get_clean();
    $fp = fopen($path_to.$filename_to.'.'.$ext, 'w');
    fwrite ($fp, $i);
    fclose ($fp);
    imagedestroy($thumb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestions for you:

- Use [`imagecopyresized()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)
- Use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) in conjunction with [`vcrop`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/vcrop.1Vi.html) on Debian
- Use [Imagick::cropImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php) or [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) in conjunction with [convert -crop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/convert)

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question here: [how to crop image in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325106/how-to-crop-image-in-codeigniter)

Basically, you provide two axes (x/y). But it will not crop the area from 0 to that axis as you think, it will actually return the part which is closer to the center. So for that reason it is possible to crop out an area between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2).